# List Item Character Uppercase

Tags: list-view, special-characters

I have a custom list. I want to,  when I add new item the list, characters are automatically converted to uppercase. How to enter characters uppercase in textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to create a calculated column and use `=UPPER([ColumnName])`.

You can read more about that here as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection4

Answer (score 2):

there are couple of ways to do it,

- easy is to use the [Caculated Column](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e6efdd33-3193-4896-a7ee-557803e89ba4/converting-the-text-in-column-to-upper-case-characters-mycolumnuppertotal?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy) as mentioned by "Jordan".
- use javascript code attached to [column] field edit box which will save the value as Upper values
- Youcan use a little jQuery to force the upper case. On keyup event, get the string and set it to upper case.
- use the  [event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg241249(v=office.14).aspx)

> ```
> C#
> public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties) {
>   string val = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();
>   properties.ListItem["Title"] = val.ToUpper();
>   properties.ListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
> }</li>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

2 more options:

- On Creation of an Item, kick of a SharePoint Designer Workflow which converts to UpperCase;
  SharePoint Designer does **not** have a Upper function but you can loop the string; see http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-propercase-strings.htm
- Less User Friendly but a good option if you can not add any coding or workflows:
  add a validation rule to the Title field and present a Validation Message when they (try to) hit Save.

*Note: I copied the Formula from my Task list*

You would think a simple

```
=IF(  [Task Name]=UPPER([Task Name])  ,true,false)
```

would do the job, but I never got this to work, it always results in true

A slight alteration does work in a Validation rule

```
=IF(  EXACT( [Task Name],UPPER([Task Name]) )  ,true,false)
```